# glulookat: Is there any good tutorial?

Tags: opengl-es

I am looking for a good and easy to understand tutorial or write-up on the use of function glulookat() ?

Especially, the last 3 paramters regarding the "up" vector.  How does it affect the orientation of the picture viewed at ?

gluLookAt  ( eyeX , eyeY , eyeZ , centerX , centerY , centerZ , upX , upY , upZ )

upX, upY, upZ 
Specifies the direction of the up vector

Answer (score 3):

Here is your documentation: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html

Anyyways, gluLookAt takes 3 vectors: eye, center, and up, and each vector needs a X, Y, and Z coordinate.

The first two vectors are locations, the first, eye, represents the location that the camera is located at, and the second is the location that the camera should be pointed at.

The problem is that there is still 360º of camera transforms that would satisfy that constraint, so we must specify a direction vector that specifies which way is "Up" in relation to the camera.

An example: If we want to have a camera at 10, 10, 0, pointing at origin, with a standard Z-up we'd call it like this:

gluLookAt(10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)